# Fillable PDF form in Azure APP service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, pdf-generation, aspose.pdf, radpdf

We have hosted the application as AppService in Azure (.NET MVC base). We have a requirement to allow the end user to fill the custom filable PDF forms in the client webpage and save the data directly for that user

1) Upload the fillable PDF form in azure storage (Master)

2) Allow the client to render it in the web page and can fill the details

3) Reupload the filled details in a User specific directory (Azure storage)

I came across the below links but it looks like they have support issues in the Cloud platform.

[RAD PDF](https://support.redsoftware.com/knowledgebase/article/View/33/0/rad-pdf-on-microsoft-azure)

[ASPose](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PDF-Editor-to-Edit-PDF-5fb73b8d#content)

We don't want to create any PDF from our application. But should be able to render the existing fillable PDF in the web form and able to re-upload after providing the details.

I dint get any clear answer on the integration and implementation from the customer care. Help if any of you have answer for this question. Thanks

Comment: Is it acceptable to render the existing fillable PDF as HTML and store result as PDF again?

Comment: Yes. we want simple save feature to be enabled on existing fillable PDF form.

Comment: Your requirements can be met by using GroupDocs.Viewer for Cloud API as it allows rendering of documents as HTML5 and PDF format, alike. It supports Azure platform as well. For further details about it, you may visit below link for your kind reference.
https://products.groupdocs.cloud/viewer/cloud

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Hi Thank you for sharing the details.. But i am wondering if i can fill the PDF and save it to the Cloud storage. I will definitely look into this.

Comment: There are some solutions but it doesn't necessarily match the design you mentioned. You could use Microsoft forms, which can be displayed as an HTML form, then perhaps convert that to PDF and store them to a storage account in Azure.

Comment: I will be given with the custom filable forms. I just need to fill it and upload it to cloud storage. I should be able to render it in the browser anytime with the information that i have filled with..